# OpenCV Mat Data type Pass by reference to other share lib

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I am a newcomer to OpenCV, currently using OpenCV2.4.8.
I have 2 source files; one is the main, and the other is compiled as a shared lib which is called by the main.cpp.

When I try to print the frame.depth() in the main after getting the frame from a web cam, it returns 0 ( which should be CV_8U); however, when I pass it to the shared lib, it returns 1 on the depth() call. I haven't changed anything on the Mat. Could anyone help to explain why the depth and type are changed after being passed to the lib; am I passing the reference incorrectly?

Thanks in advance.

Dick

Here is the source code for Main.cpp

```
using namespace cv;

void onMouse(int event, int x ,int y, int flags,void* param);

int main(int argc,char** argv){
       VideoCapture cap(-1);
       Mat frame;
       Mat grey;
       double width;
       double height;

       namedWindow("WebCam",1);
       cvSetMouseCallback("WebCam",onMouse,NULL);
       width = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
       height = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
       grey = Mat(height,width,CV_8UC1);
       while(1){
                  cap >> frame;
                  printf("frame.depth %d\n",frame.depth()); // it will return 0;
                  printf("frame.type %d\n",frame.type()); //  it will return 16;
                  preprocessing(frame,grey); // pass to share lib
                  imshow("WebCam",grey);
                  if(cvWaitKey(1)>=0){
                            break;
                }
        }
        cvDestroyWindow("WebCam");
        return 0;
}
```

Here is the Source for preprocess.cpp; it is compiled to libpreprocess.so

```
void preprocessing(const Mat &imgSrc,Mat &resultImg)
{
    printf("imgSrc.depth %d\n",imgSrc.depth()); // here, it will return 1;
    printf("imgSrc.type %d\n",imgSrc.type()); // here it will return 1;
}
```

Comment: interesting. can't reproduce, neither with 3.0, nor with 2.4.2 (win box here) . i get 0 16 in both cases.

Comment: how does the header for your shared lib look like ? any chance you swapped imgSrc, resultImg in the declaration ?